# Problems with setting up sequence

Tags: excel, vba, integer

I have prepared the following macro so I can shift cells right in a few tabs.
When I try to run it says there's a problem with the integer:

```
' Roll forward the analysis at the bottom of the table

Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range



Dim myrange As Integer
For Range = 1 To 7
    
    Set myrange = Worksheets("South Sales").Range("C30:N70")
    
    For Each mycell In myrange
    
    If mycell.Value > 0 Then

    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    
    Range("C6").Select

 ' Move onto next tab, macro starts again from the beginning for 31 tabs
 
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
    Next Range

' Goes back to the front sheet

    Sheets("Front Sheet").Select
    
' Stops the freeze of the screen updating

    Application.StatusBar = False

' Message box to confirm macro completed.

    MsgBox "Refresh complete"

Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim myrange As Range`

Comment: Your variable `myrange ` is declared twice. Also, variable `Range ` is not declared. Also, lines `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents` makes no sense the repetition. One should be enough